# Using input & output channels in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to use channels to pass data to and back from go routines. At some point during execution the process freezes up. I haven't been able to determine when or why via Delve. What exactly am I doing wrong here?

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    records := liaison.Parse(r) // Parse incoming JSON into a slice.
    nRecords := len(records)
    in, out := make(chan map[string]string), make(chan map[string]string)

    // Start a go routine for each CPU core.          
    for i := 0; i < nCores; i++ {
        go clean(in, out)
    }

    // Pass each map in the slice to the input channel.
    for _, record := range records {
        in <- record
    }

    // Replace each index of the records slice with cleaned data.
    for i := 0; i < nRecords; i++ {
        cleaned := <-out
        records[i] = cleaned
    }

    close(in)
    close(out)

    liaison.Respond(w, &records)
}

func clean(in, out chan map[string]string) {
    record := <-in
    // run cleaning rules on input record.
    out <- record
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The program uses unbuffered channels. Communication on an unbuffered channel does not succeed until the both the sender and receiver are ready.

If `nRecords` is greater than `nCores`, then the program will deadlock: The cleaner goroutines cannot send to `out` until the handler goroutine receives from `out`.  The handler goroutine cannot receive because it blocks on sending to `in`.

If `nRecords` is less than `nCores`, the cleaners that didn't get work will panic on send to `out`.  When `close(in)` is called from the handler goroutine, the cleaners that didn't get work will receive a zero value from `<-in`. The cleaner goroutines will process that zero value and attempt to send to `out`.  Concurrently with this, the handler goroutine closes `out`.  The application panics because send on a closed channel is not allowed.

Here's a fix:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    records := liaison.Parse(r) // Parse incoming JSON into a slice.
    nRecords := len(records)
    in, out := make(chan map[string]string), make(chan map[string]string)

    // Start a go routine for each CPU core.
    for i := 0; i < nCores; i++ {
        go clean(in, out)
    }

    // Start a goroutine to feed the data. This this allows
    // the handler goroutine to continue to receiving on out.
    go func() {
        for _, record := range records {
            in <- record
        }
        // Close the channel. This causes the cleaners to exit
        // from the for / range loops.
        close(in)
    }()

    // Replace each index of the records slice with cleaned data.
    for i := 0; i < nRecords; i++ {
        cleaned := <-out
        records[i] = cleaned
    }

    liaison.Respond(w, &records)
}

func clean(in, out chan map[string]string) {
    // use for / range to read records until in is closed.
    for record := range in {
        // run cleaning rules on input record.
        out <- record
    }
}
```

An alternative approach is to use to change `in` to a buffered channel with space for all records:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    records := liaison.Parse(r) // Parse incoming JSON into a slice.
    nRecords := len(records)
    in := make(chan map[string]string, nRecords) // <-- note second argument
    out := make(chan map[string]string)

    // Start a go routine for each CPU core.
    for i := 0; i < nCores; i++ {
        go clean(in, out)
    }

    for _, record := range records {
        // this will not block because cap(in) == len(records).
        in <- record
    }
    close(in)

    // Replace each index of the records slice with cleaned data.
    for i := 0; i < nRecords; i++ {
        cleaned := <-out
        records[i] = cleaned
    }

    liaison.Respond(w, &records)
}
```